# material ui styled components in mobx observable

Tags: material-ui, mobx, mobx-react, emotion

I can`t add components created with styled of @mui/material/styles to observable objects. is there any configuration required to fix this?

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new ObservableObjectAdministration (mobx.esm.js:4402:42)
    at asObservableObject (mobx.esm.js:4829:13)
    at asDynamicObservableObject (mobx.esm.js:3267:12)
    at Function.object (mobx.esm.js:1317:155)
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-snowflake-j687ub?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: changed code-example (includes state object now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such cases you can use `observable.ref` ([docs](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#observableref)), because you basically only want to track reassignments, you don't really want to make the whole object (or in this case even Component) observable.

So just change it to:

```
  @observable.ref
  public component: React.ReactNode = null;
```

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220879]

Comment: thanks in the simple example this will work, but we use more complex state objects and depend on a whole observable state-object

Comment: Then make an example with more complex state? :) How could I know in advance that in reality you use something different? Be more specific next time, please.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I changed the code example

Comment: Same thing, just mark component as `ref` https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-73220879-neb8jl?file=/src/App.tsx It's not any different, you just now have inner state object inside of your main state object (`StateHandlerClass`). Which does not make much sense in that example, but not a big deal, maybe you have more complex thing in reality